# One or two tables: that is the quest*on

Tags: mysql, database

I'm trying to setup a database schema for a company which works as a middle man (selling items collected from **vendors** to **buyers**).

Both of these entities (vendors and buyers) can be generalized as a **client** - they both have very similar attributes (name, email, password, address, etc...) and multiple other entities depend on this. For example **invoices** are generated for **buyers** and **settlements** (different type of paperwork) are generated for **vendors**. The thing is that one person (a **client**) can by buyer and vendor in the same time.

The dilema I'm having is how to setup the database structure for this?

At the moment I'm more in favor of having both vendors and buyers in one table and distinguish between them using something like **roles** column. Thanks to this approach I would avoid the data redundancy and I could still create views to easily separate vendors from buyers to the outside world.

Am I thinking about this correctly? How would you typically solve this situation? Would it be better to use two separate tables?

Thank you for your advice and experiences :)

Comment: You're thinking about this correctly, but the solution has to be the one most fitting to your business model. I don't think we know enough about that. I don't see how a roles column would help - everyone has the potential to be both

Answer (score 1):

If you know the usecases, think about, what could be a rough solution. But that is quite dangerous, at the end sometimes the ingenious datamodel becomes too complicated to understand and maintain.

How important is it to decide now, will your datamodel or organization be fit for a later change?.  Can you be agile? Then implement, what is best for your current usecases, nothing more!

btw. 
if there is a 1 to 2 relationsship between person and role, you should factor out the role, not duplicate the data, or create two attributes, isBuyer and isVendor, or put in these attributes references to the buyer- and vendor-specific data, if there is any.

Comment: Cool thanks, the isBuyer, isVendor is a good idea, I don't know why I went with the roles in the first place. Now when I think about it this makes perfect sense and will make it easier to separate those two.

As far as the flexibility goes. I though about it this way: If I need to add vendor/buyer specific information in the future I can transform it to a ISA relationship by adding two (optional) columns - 1:1 relation to **vendorDetails** and **buyerDetails**.

Are there any major downsides that I'm missing (should be aware of)?

Comment: if the two roles have much in common, it might later be better to not use an attribute in the person table at all and create a roletable where there is a back reference to person. Then you can specialize the roles and do not have to handle two different attributes all the time. Perhaps there can come more roles like employee, government, ....